# How can I add my own action that I can give access in the SharePoint Portal to my API to allow

Tags: api, sharepoint

I have an `API` that I have deployed to `Azure`.

This `API` has a number of `Actions`. I would like to be able to add these `Actions` to my `API` and configure them in a client app that uses the `API`

Could anybody provide some guidance on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean here. You have an API and want to configure them in a client app? Do you you mean you want to call the API in your Client App?

In this case, assuming your API is REST, you can use HttpClient and use the PostAsyc(), PutAsync(), DeleteAsync, GetAsync() methods with the url and httpcontent you API requires to sent.

```
  var httpClient = new HttpClient
  {
       BaseAddress = new Uri("...")
  };

  var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"api/....");
  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
    ...
  ]
```

Sander